# How to exclude one statement from current Sql transaction for Sql id generator?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2, locking

I would like to implement id generator to be able to have unique records identification for multiple tables and be able to assign id to structures of new records formed on client side.

Usually obvious and standard answer is Guid, but I want to use int because of space efficiency and human readability.

It's ok to have gaps in id sequence - which will happen with unfinished transactions, lost client connections and so on.

For implementation I would have a table `Counters` with field `NextId int` and increment that counter any time id is requested. I may increment that id by more than 1 when I need range of ids for multiple or bulk inserts.

To avoid locking bottlenecks when updating `Counters` table I need to make id requests atomic and outside of any other transactions. So my question is how to do that ?

It's not a problem on application level - it can make one atomic transaction request to get pool of ids and then use those ids in another bigger transaction to insert records.

But what do I do if I want to get new ids inside Stored Procedure or Trigger ?

If I wrap that `update Counter set NextId=NextId+1` table request into nested transaction `begin tran` ... `commit tran` it's not going to exclude it from locking until outer big transaction ends.

Is there any way to exclude that one Sql statement from current transaction so that locking ends right when statement ends and it does not participate in rollback if outer transaction is rolled back.

Comment: Why aren't you just using `INT IDENTITY` to get consecutive ID numbers??

Comment: If you were on SQL2012, you could have used Sequences (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)

Comment: how many records do you expect to enter into this system?  the reason I ask is that if the incoming volume is low and you do not need to do bulk uploads, you can use a table with a trigger.

Comment: 50 million records. May be I will need bigint instead of int to allow big gaps, but still same question applies. Another thing - it's ok if record inserted later has lower id than one of records inserted before. All I need is uniqueness. If I need sequence I will use something else.

Comment: @Raj: How does a table with a trigger solves locking problem ?

Comment: Can you explain the need to have non-repeating ids across multiple tables?

Comment: also, is it 50 M records a day? an hour? a year? a second?

Comment: @Raj: it's 50M total, it may be 10K a day or so. Bulk insert could be like 1K at once.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23795/discussion-between-raj-more-and-alpav)

Comment: @marc_s: you mean instead of updating, insert into Counter table and get new id ? Even if I don't index it, doesn't it cause hot spot problems ?

Comment: @alpav: **NO!** those "hotspot" problems were an issue in SQL Server 6.5 - not anymore ever since! Having an ever-increasing index is actually **good** for performance since the data is being inserted on a page that's already in memory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a second connection. You cannot have multiple transactions at once per connection.